# Regular expression, sed, path extraction

Tags: regex, sed, sh

This is a question about regular expression.
I have the following code:

### Program

```
#!/bin/sh

temp="/home/user/game/log.txt"
echo $temp | sed -e "s#\(.*\)/.*#\1#"
```

### Output

> /home/user/game

### Question

What is the meaning of this guy --- `s#\(.*\)/.*#\1#`?

I search from the web and I know some meaning, for example:

`s` - substitute

`.` - any word

`*` - the word in front of this can repeat 0 to infinite times

But I still don't understand the meaning of this code,although I know the function

Comment: You should use [basename](http://www.ss64.com/bash/basename.html) for this just FYI.

Comment: `*` means 0 or more `+` is 1 or more

Comment: shyam
>
Thanks for your correction ^^

Comment: squiguy > Thanks for your suggestion, I have read your reference@@"

Comment: @squiguy I assume that you meant `dirname`, not `basename`.

Comment: @sflee `man sed` or `info sed` is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"s#\(.*\)/.*#\1#"
```

`s` is the substitute command, its format is like `s[DELIM]regex[DELIM]replace[DELIM]`. and DELIM can be any character delimiting the arguments. In your case, the delimiter is `#`. In the regex part you have:

```
\(.*\)/.*
```

Here the match between `\(` and `)` is captured, meaning that you can refer to it in the replace part of the command. Inside the capture you are [greedy] matching anything. But this match has to stop somewhere because after the capture there is a slash `/` which should be matched. Since the captured `.*` is greedy, sed will match and capture until the last slash. Then, it will match `.*` without capturing. This part won't contain any slashes (due to previous greedy match). Thus, the regex will match all input if it contains a slash, but it will also remember the part until the last slash.

the replace part:

```
\1
```

replaces the matched pattern with the captured part. All in all, this command matches files within some directory and will remove filename, leaving only the directory name.

Answer (score 1):

```
 s#\(.*\)/.*#\1
```

- `s`: substitue command
- `#`: delimeter of the three parts the `s` command has
- `\(\)`: a group that can later be referenced
- `.`: any character
- `/`: a literal slash
- `.*`: any number of characters
- `\1`: referecen to the first group

The `s` command has three parts:

1. The command `s` itself
2. What to match, including definiton of groups: `\(.*\)/.*`
3. What to output i place of what was matched: `\1`

So this takes everything up the last `/` as the first group and prints it by referencing it with `\1`.